# Wildfly migration issue keycloak

Tags: wildfly

I was tasked to move from Wildfly 11 to 26.01 and need some help getting the legacy command to work. I'm just learning Wildfly so at a beginner level here.  I know I have to use elytron, but don't see an example that marries up with my existing code.

```
JBOSS_CLI="/opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect"

$JBOSS_CLI --command="/subsystem=security/security-domain=myAPP/authentication=classic/:add(login-modules=[{ "code" => "org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakLoginModule","flag" => "required"}])"
```

but I get errors and looking via the jboss-cli.sh I see that authentication is not available.  I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

I tried this, but it fails

```
$JBOSS_CLI --command="/subsystem=elytron/security-domain=DSD/authentication=classic/:add(login-modules=[{ "code" => "org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakLoginModule","flag" => "required"}])"
```

Answer (score 0):

The legacy subsystem was removed from the default configuration in WildFly 25, and now only works in admin-only mode ([blog post](https://www.wildfly.org/news/2021/09/27/WildFly-Changes/)). The [migration guide](https://docs.wildfly.org/26/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#Migrate_Legacy_Security_to_Elytron_Security) should be helpful in moving the existing configuration to Elytron.